# Write the http response to a file

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to write a simple node.js program that proxies requests and writes the response to a file. I'm using [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to do the proxying. 
When I try to pipe the response to a file (or the process.stdout for testing), it's empty / zero bytes. I'm not sure why but I think it might be because the stream has been closed since the response has been sent back to the client.

How can I get this to work?

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {
  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 80
  });
});

server.proxy.on('end', function (response) {
  response.pipe(process.stdout); // NOTHING IS WRITTEN TO THE STDOUT
});

server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: On end event response is already empty, and response is writeable stream, you can pipe only read to write(readableStream.pipe(writeableStream)). for ex. you can pipe request: `req.pipe(process.stdout);`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
  var http = require('http'),
  httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
  var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var _write = res.write;
    res.write = function(data){
      process.stdout.write(data); // here we get all incoming data
      _write.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 80  
    });
  }).listen(8000);
```